# nodejs : mongodb insert data with mondo db object reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to nodejs: i want toi have made connection in db_mongo.js file and calling that file from another page and trying to insert.. but it gives

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1)
```

but when i am trying to insert from "db_mongo" after creating connection it is working there.

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
url = require('url');


// var db = require('../db');


var mongo = require( '../db_mongo' );


http.createServer(function(request, response){
var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
    var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query;

var setval = {username: query.name, email: query.email, password: query.pass};
//     db.query('INSERT INTO users  SET ?', setval, function (err, res) {
//         if (err)
//             throw err;
//
// });


if (mongo) {console.log("mongo  connected here ss");}

var userCollection =   mongo.collection('users');

userCollection.insert((setval, function(err, result) {
    if(err) { throw err; }
    res.write("<p>Product inserted:</p>");
    res.end("<p>" + result[0].make + " " + result[0].model + "</p>");
}));


    // db.collection('users').insertOne( {
    //     username: query.name, email: query.email, password: query.pass
    // }, function(err, result) {
    //     assert.equal(err, null);
    //     console.log("Inserted a document into users");
    //     callback();
    // });
// };

// insertDocument(db, function() {
// });




}).listen(8001);
```

**db_mongo**

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url_db = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

module.exports = function(callback) {
    MongoClient.connect(url_db, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your module `db_mongo` exports a function, not a DB instance. So, to get instance, you have to do like

```
var mongo = require( '../db_mongo' )();  // if you don't care about callback
```

In the above code, variable mongo is just a reference to the exported function. You cannot do `mongo.collection('users')` on it.

Try this out,

```
require( '../db_mongo' )(function(err, db){
  if(err){
    //error handling
    return;
  }
  var userCollection = db.collection('users');
  // your code goes here
  db.close();
});
```

For more details, check [this](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html) out